# python: csv files wont put data into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i am trying to put the iris data set into a list however when i try to read the lines in the file it doesn't separate each value and instead puts it in 1 string. how do i fix this so that it opens and separate the data?
some of the data:

```
sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,setosa
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,setosa
```

code:

```
import csv

with open("iris.csv", "r") as csv_iris:
    read = csv.reader(csv_iris, delimiter = ",")

    for line in csv_iris:
        print(line[0])
```

output:

```
s
5
4
4
4
5
5
4
```

what output should be:

```
sepal_length
5.1
4.9
4.7
4.6
5.0
5.4
```

Comment: You should be iterating over the `read` (csv reader) object. `for line in read`

Answer (score 1):

You were iterating over the file rather than the csv reader. That caused the first character of each line to be printed.

```
import csv

with open("iris.csv", "r") as csv_iris:
    read = csv.reader(csv_iris, delimiter = ",")    
    for line in read:
        print(line[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I commented the mistake

```
with open('iris.csv','r') as csv_iris:
    read = csv.reader(csv_iris,delimiter=',')
#Instead of calling for read, you called for csv_iris
    for line in read:
        print(line[0])
```